# how to add date filter web part to web page using c# code(SSOM) in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, development, solution-package, ssom

Please guide me on how to add date filter web part to web page using SSOM

Comment: I am also adding date filter web part to web page using c# but still not succeed.